# JavaScript project rock-paper-scissors---issues with console during first load of the page

Tags: javascript

When you open the page for the first time, you are presented with a prompt box like intended, but you want to open dev-tools/console to watch the console.log messages appear.

For some reason, if u open dev-tools/console **after** the prompt window pops, console.logs don't appear and you have to play the game till the end to see them.

Here is the link to the page : https://kloba1004.github.io/project-rock-paper-scissors/

Can anyone give your honest opinion on my code given that I am not experienced:

```js
let userWins = 0,
  computerWins = 0;

function game() {
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    let playerSelection = prompt("Choose rock, paper or scissors: "),
      computerSelection;

    const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

    let computerPlay = Math.random() * 10;

    if (playerSelection !== null) {
      playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();
    }

    while ((playerSelection === null) || (playerSelection === '') || (!choices.includes(playerSelection))) {

      if (playerSelection === '' || playerSelection === null) {
        playerSelection = prompt("U entered absolutely nothing. Try again...Rock, paper or scissors:")
      } else {
        playerSelection = prompt("You typed it wrong. Try again. Choose rock, paper or scissors: ");
        if (playerSelection !== null) {
          playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();
        };
      }
    }

    playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

      if (computerPlay >= 0 && computerPlay < 3.5) {
        computerSelection = 'rock';
        if (playerSelection === 'scissors') {
          computerWins = computerWins + 1;
          return `You lost this round. Rock beats scissors.`;
        } else if (playerSelection === 'paper') {
          userWins = userWins + 1;
          return `You won this round. Paper beats rock.`;
        } else {
          return `Neither won this round. Rock can\'t beat rock.`;
        }
      } else if (computerPlay >= 3.5 && computerPlay < 6.5) {
        computerSelection = 'paper';
        if (playerSelection === 'scissors') {
          userWins = userWins + 1;
          return `You won this round. Scissors beat paper.`;
        } else if (playerSelection === 'rock') {
          computerWins = computerWins + 1;
          return `You lost this round. Paper beats rock.`;
        } else {
          return `Neither won this round. Paper can\'t beat paper.`
        }
      } else {
        computerSelection = 'scissors';
        if (playerSelection === 'rock') {
          userWins = userWins + 1;
          return `You won this round. Rock beats scissors.`;
        } else if (playerSelection === 'paper') {
          computerWins = computerWins + 1;
          return `You lost this round. Scissors beat paper.`;
        } else {
          return `Neither win. Scissors can\'t beat scissors.`;
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) + `Current score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`);

  }

  if (userWins > computerWins) {
    console.log(`You won the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`);
  } else if (userWins === computerWins) {
    console.log(`Neither won the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`);
  } else {
    console.log(`You lost the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`);
  }
}

game();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @iota To be honest, I don't know how to do it. The program executes properly. But console.log doesn't show during the first load of the page, and I seriously don't know which exact part of the program causes it, thus linking the github file instead of pasting whole code inside the post.

Comment: Post your code here, not at an external site. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like this:

```js
function game() {
    // Loop
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let playerSelection = prompt("Choose rock, paper or scissors: "),
        computerSelection;

      const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

      let computerPlay = Math.random() * 10;

      if (playerSelection !== null) {
        playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();
      }

      while (
        playerSelection === null ||
        playerSelection === "" ||
        !choices.includes(playerSelection)
      ) {
        if (playerSelection === "" || playerSelection === null) {
          playerSelection = prompt(
            "U entered absolutely nothing. Try again...Rock, paper or scissors:"
          );
        } else {
          playerSelection = prompt(
            "You typed it wrong. Try again. Choose rock, paper or scissors: "
          );
          if (playerSelection !== null) {
            playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();
          }
        }
      }

      playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();

      function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
        ...
      }

      console.log(
        playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) +
          `Current score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`
      );
    }

    // Console logs
    if (userWins > computerWins) {
      console.log(
        `You won the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`
      );
    } else if (userWins === computerWins) {
      console.log(
        `Neither won the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
        `You lost the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`
      );
    }
  }
```

As you can see, the `console.log`s are placed after the `for` loop, which prompts the user.
So naturally they would execute after the game ends.

### Update:

Regarding the first `console.log`, it executed at the end of loop because you are declaring the `playRound` function at each iteration (and it gets pushed to stack).

To get the expected behavior, move it's declaration like this:

```js
<script>
  let userWins = 0,
    computerWins = 0;

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection, computerPlay) {
        if (computerPlay >= 0 && computerPlay < 3.5) {
            computerSelection = "rock";
            if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
            computerWins = computerWins + 1;
            return `You lost this round. Rock beats scissors.`;
            } else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
            userWins = userWins + 1;
            return `You won this round. Paper beats rock.`;
            } else {
            return `Neither won this round. Rock can\'t beat rock.`;
            }
        } else if (computerPlay >= 3.5 && computerPlay < 6.5) {
            computerSelection = "paper";
            if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
            userWins = userWins + 1;
            return `You won this round. Scissors beat paper.`;
            } else if (playerSelection === "rock") {
            computerWins = computerWins + 1;
            return `You lost this round. Paper beats rock.`;
            } else {
            return `Neither won this round. Paper can\'t beat paper.`;
            }
        } else {
            computerSelection = "scissors";
            if (playerSelection === "rock") {
            userWins = userWins + 1;
            return `You won this round. Rock beats scissors.`;
            } else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
            computerWins = computerWins + 1;
            return `You lost this round. Scissors beat paper.`;
            } else {
            return `Neither win. Scissors can\'t beat scissors.`;
            }
        }
        }

  function game() {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let playerSelection = prompt("Choose rock, paper or scissors: "),
        computerSelection;

      const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

      let computerPlay = Math.random() * 10;

      if (playerSelection !== null) {
        playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();
      }

      while (
        playerSelection === null ||
        playerSelection === "" ||
        !choices.includes(playerSelection)
      ) {
        if (playerSelection === "" || playerSelection === null) {
          playerSelection = prompt(
            "U entered absolutely nothing. Try again...Rock, paper or scissors:"
          );
        } else {
          playerSelection = prompt(
            "You typed it wrong. Try again. Choose rock, paper or scissors: "
          );
          if (playerSelection !== null) {
            playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();
          }
        }
      }

      playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();

      console.log(
        playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection, computerPlay) +
          `Current score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`
      );
    }

    if (userWins > computerWins) {
      console.log(
        `You won the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`
      );
    } else if (userWins === computerWins) {
      console.log(
        `Neither won the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
        `You lost the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`
      );
    }
  }

  game();
</script>
```

Comment: After the first game of 5 rounds ends, you can see console.logs of each round during the next games. The problem is the first one.

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your help. Secondly, I checked your code execution, but doesn't it show exactly the same thing? Every game in which console/dev tools was open before the actual game start shows all of the console.logs after every round of the game. If dev tools/console is not opened before the prompt window, console.logs will be shown only at the end of the game. Without html+button I am still not able to solve it in some other way. Sorry for bothering you in any case.

Comment: I tested it with refreshing the page, but you're right; if you open it the first time it's the same as before

Comment: I'm not sure if that is solvable at all without adding some html (buttons with events for calling the function to start) and opening dev tools before clicking the button. Because, the thing is, even if u add a button and click it without opening dev tools beforehand, same issue will appear.

Comment: Seems like the prompt call is blocking console.logs. I suggest you ditch prompt and use a modal, if you decide to go the html route

Answer (score 0):

The function `game()` is called right after loading the page, which it will be fired and shows up directly the alert modal, I would suggest adding a button with `onclick` attribute and call the function from there, so you can before start playing open the console

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock | paper | scissors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="game()">Play</button>
    <script>

        let userWins = 0,
            computerWins = 0;
        
        function game() {    
            for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        
                let playerSelection  = prompt("Choose rock, paper or scissors: "),
                    computerSelection;
        
                const choices = [ 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
        
                let computerPlay= Math.random()*10;
        
                if (playerSelection!==null) {
                    playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();
                }
        
                while ((playerSelection===null) || (playerSelection==='') || (!choices.includes(playerSelection)) ) {
        
                    if (playerSelection==='' || playerSelection===null) {
                        playerSelection = prompt("U entered absolutely nothing. Try again...Rock, paper or scissors:")
                    }
                    else {
                        playerSelection = prompt("You typed it wrong. Try again. Choose rock, paper or scissors: ");
                        if (playerSelection!==null) {
                            playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();
                        };
                    }
                }
        
                playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim();
        
                function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
        
                    if (computerPlay>=0 && computerPlay<3.5) {
                        computerSelection= 'rock';
                        if (playerSelection==='scissors') {
                            computerWins= computerWins+1;
                            return `You lost this round. Rock beats scissors.`;
                        } else if (playerSelection==='paper') {
                            userWins= userWins+1;
                            return `You won this round. Paper beats rock.`;
                        } else{
                            return `Neither won this round. Rock can\'t beat rock.`;
                        }
                    }
        
                    else if (computerPlay>=3.5 && computerPlay<6.5) {
                        computerSelection= 'paper';
                        if (playerSelection==='scissors') {
                            userWins= userWins+1;
                            return `You won this round. Scissors beat paper.`;
                        } else if (playerSelection==='rock') {
                            computerWins= computerWins+1;
                            return `You lost this round. Paper beats rock.`;
                        } else{
                            return `Neither won this round. Paper can\'t beat paper.`
                        }
                    } 
        
                    else {
                        computerSelection= 'scissors';
                        if (playerSelection==='rock') {
                            userWins= userWins+1;
                            return `You won this round. Rock beats scissors.`;
                        } else if (playerSelection==='paper') {
                            computerWins= computerWins+1;
                            return `You lost this round. Scissors beat paper.`;
                        } else{
                            return `Neither win. Scissors can\'t beat scissors.`;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                console.log(playRound(playerSelection,computerSelection)+`Current score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`);
        
            }  
        
            if (userWins>computerWins) {
                console.log(`You won the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`);
            } else if (userWins===computerWins) {
                console.log(`Neither won the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`);
            } else {
                console.log(`You lost the game. Final score is ${userWins} : ${computerWins}.`);
            }
        }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have just done that. Works like a charm, thank you. I am still learning, so this was my first ever made JavaScript event. Still not satisfied, because I was requested to provide empty html file with only script tags and code. I still hope there might be a solution without anything other than plain JavaScript because I had to add html+button tag for this.